# Translate text with php script and translate.google.com

Tags: php, google-translate

I am new to php, and I am working on a school project that need to translate text files (.txt). So I am trying to translate with translate.google.com and I have about 600 text files. Doing that manually will take long long time. So for that reason I tried to make simple php script that send text to translate.google.com and retrieve the translated text.
 
I have noticed that when you type text in translate.google.com  and you click translate, the URL is chancing into "translate.google.com/#mk/en/This is a simple".
We can see /#mk/en/  writen languages - translated languages, and after that goes the text that I have typed and needs to be translated.
To this point I know what I am doing, but the translated text is kept in another box, in a span tag with id="result_box" and I don't know how to get the translated text from there. 
 
This is my code so far, and I am having trouble how to get back the translated text.

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$handle = @fopen("sample.txt", "r");
$text="";
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

        $text=$text.$buffer;

    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}


    $html="http://translate.google.com/#mk/en/$text";
    echo $html;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
    //Here I don't know what to do
    foreach ($nodes as $node)
            echo  $node->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but your solution won't even work. Everything after the # in your uri is normally parsed by your browser (in this case by javascript) and wont be sent to the Google-server. (Try turning off javascript in your browser and reloading the page, you won't see the translation)

Answer (score 0):

Put the text files into a website and then use google translate to flip it into Swahili or whatever. right click on teh page and fiddle it through . Just done it...it works.